# Mysql stuck when trying to export or import

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I installed a fresh ubuntu 15 and installed mysql-server. I created a database and tried to export it but the terminal is getting stuck and nothing is happening[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkXzR.png)

See the screenshot, it is stuck like that forever. Also I can't import anything. I used apt-get install mysql-server to install mysql, I installed nothing else in this OS, I just ran apt-get update first.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 10):

use mysqldump not mysql.

mysql is for connecting or importing (with <).

Answer (score 7):

That's because it's waiting for input.

The command:

```
mysql -uroot -pmysql student
```

Opens up a MySQL shell, like you were using above, is also automatically selects the `student` database.

```
mysql -uroot -pmysql student > test.sql
```

When you do this, it's "stuck" because it's waiting for you to enter a command.  You are saving the output to a file, so you're not seeing it on the screen.

What I assume you want is `mysqldump`:

```
mysqldump -uroot -pmysql student > test.sql
```

Comment: still not working for me ..